# How to get one js file to another project folder in node js

Tags: node.js

`get(function (){
    console.log(' Hello world');
});`

I have this js file that contains some message in a project folder in my node eclipse. I want access that js file to my current project folder using path. How to access that file to my current folder. Please give me the code for both js files for accessing and exporting.
Please help me.
Thank you

Comment: use require('file-name.js');

Comment: I dont realy understand for what you are asking. But if you want to only use the js file you can do it with require, like normal. e.g. `const modul = require('../other/project/modul.js')`

Comment: @Julian I want to get a js file from another project folder to my current project folder like the above code. But that was not working.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:
// common.js

```
module.exports = {
    theFunc: function(obj){
         console.log(' Hello world');
    };
}
```

// another.js

```
var common = require('common.js');  // with full path
common.theFunc();
```

Comment: This was a nice code. But when I try to run my another.js, it shows the error **Cannot find module '../Work/routes/get.js'**. and this is my path I set to the another.js. another.js I just say, file is different.

Comment: is this file get.js outside your current project? 
you can try this code into any demo project for understand.

Comment: Yes. get.js is outside of my current project. I want to get this get.js file to my current project. and show the content. Thank you

Comment: then how is it possible. will you upload both these project at time of deployment?
You need to put this into same project

Comment: yes it is possible with hack, when ever your node server started you need to pull that file from that server via http.request & create a file on your current server or store in node caches.

Comment: No, I want to Know it will work or not, that is can I access some files from outside of my project.

Comment: no, according to standards. and this hack is wrong approach. Tell me what are you creating now, so i could suggest you something better.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116873/discussion-between-jain-and-melbin-mathai).

Comment: Ok, if it in a same project, and different folder how to do?

Comment: provide relative path of that file like css.
eg: ../<folder-name>/get.js